# end cron job after specified time

Tags: python, macos, unix, cron

I am trying to run a Python script on OS X every 2 hours for 48 hours.

```
* */2 * * * nohup sudo python curl.py
```

However, it is my understanding that it is not possible to specify an end time in the command. Is there any way to automatically stop the cron job or `pkill` after 48 hours (or 24 executions)? Also, I may have to schedule additional cron jobs while the first one is still running, so I can't use `crontab -r`. Is this something I have to code in the Python script itself to check if it has already been run x times?

Comment: Yes, have your Python script count how many times it has been run, or how much time has elapsed from the first invocation.

Comment: On OS X you should generally use `LaunchDaemon` rather than `cron`, although I don't know if it has a way to do this limited repetition, either.

Comment: If you use `LaunchDaemon`, you could possibly combine `StartCalendarInterval` with `PathState`. The script could delete the file being tested by `PathState` after it runs 24 times. But I'm not sure if this combination works this way, I haven't tried it.

Comment: @kindall Thanks. Would it cause any problems if I were to schedule another cron job running the same file/script?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem so long as you don't let them start at exactly the same time so they're both updating the "number of runs left" file simultaneously.

Comment: @Barmar I am looking into `launchd` and may end up using that instead. According to this [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/501654), however, it looks like `PathState` cannot be used to specify when a job should be stopped.

Comment: I'm not sure that answer is relevant. You don't want a running job to stop, you just want to prevent it from restarting.

Comment: @kindall Great. Any suggestions on how to count time elapsed or number of invocations? Or just what to search on Google to point me in the right direction? Can't seem to think of the right phrase to search.

Comment: @kindall But they'll both keep their count in the same file, won't they? You'd need to give them an argument that tells which file to use for the counter, so they don't step on each others' toes.

Comment: Write it to a text file... something in /etc would be good on Unix boxen.

Comment: They won't step on each other's toes. If you say run 50 times, the two cron jobs will run the script a total of 50 times.

Comment: @kindall I'm still trying to figure out how to count how many times a script has been run. Is `trace` the right module to use?

Comment: No module needed. Just store a number in a text file and have your script read it, decrement it, and write it back out each time it runs. When it's zero, exit without doing anything.